# Unable to set a v1 cgroup limit

Tags: cgroup

I have a pids.max limit set to `400`, I want to set it to `max`

It is found in `/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/pids.max`,

```
sudo cgget -g pids:/
/:
pids.current: 278
pids.max: 400
```

I would think that I could set it by running the following command, but `pids.max` stays at 400.

```
$ sudo cgset -r pids.max=500 pids:/
$ sudo cgget -g pids:/
/:
pids.current: 278
pids.max: 400
```

How do I change `pids.max`?

Answer (score 3):

It's a syntax problem.

[`man cgset`](https://manpages.debian.org/cgroup-tools/cgset.1#SYNOPSIS) tells:

> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
> cgset [-r <name=value>] <cgroup_path> ...
> cgset --copy-from <source_cgroup_path> <cgroup_path> ...
> ```

the cgroup_path for your case is `/`, not `uids:/`. `cgset` will silently do nothing and return no error when applied on an non-existing cgroup. This can be verified with [`strace`](https://manpages.debian.org/strace/strace.1) (using `strace -e trace=open,openat,close,write`):

non-working `cgset -r pids.max=max pids:/`:

```
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/pids:/pids.max", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

working `cgset -r pids.max=max /`:

```
[...]
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/sys/fs/cgroup/pids/pids.max", O_RDWR|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
write(3, "max", 3)                      = 3
close(3)                                = 0
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Of course you could also write directly from shell to this pseudo-file to do the same, but using `sudo` makes it more complicated (eg: having to use the `tee` command rather than a shell redirection).

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but even with the right syntax the pids.max value remains at 400! I run this command `sudo cgset -r pids.max=max /`.

Comment: Running `echo 'max' | sudo tee /sys/fs/cgroup/pids/pids.max` gives me a tee error, 'Actie is niet toegestaan', which translates to `action is not permitted/allowed`

Comment: Actually, I think the problem might be my server provider. I found [this StackOverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61074853/2302759) saying that the server provider limited their max tasks to 700, it makes no sense that my pids.max is set to 400 anyway, and I can't edit the value. I even noticed that the cgroup fs was set to read-only, but remounting it to rw still made no difference.

Comment: Yes running an unprivileged/rootless (user namespace) LXC container gets me an `EACCESS` error when writing to the pids.max. Which makes sense. But for your case it's perhaps `EPERM`? Anyway, combined with the "never return an error" used by the command gets that it won't do anything and won't tell it.

Comment: Entering mount+pid+cgroups (and no others) namespaces (using something like `nsenter -t $(su -c 'lxc info -Hp -n user-buster-amd64' user) -p -m -C  cgset -r pids.max=500 /`  from the real host root user allows to change it. That's clearly something at the hands of the provider.